# Aerospike docker - 100L, 'UDF: Execution Error 1

Tags: aerospike

I deployed an Aerospike container using the [official docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/aerospike/aerospike-server/). When I try to execute `test_list = client.llist(key, 'test_list')`, my Python client script returns the following error:

```
exception.UDFError: (100L, 'UDF: Execution Error 1', 'src/main/llist/llist_operations.c', 93)
```

I looked at the Aerospike logs and found that each time this code is executed, the error below gets printed:

```
: WARNING (udf): (src/main/mod_lua.c:599) Lua Create Error: module 'llist' not found:
    no field package.preload['llist']
    no file './llist.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.3/llist.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/llist.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/llist/init.lua'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/llist.lua'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/external/llist.lua'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/llist.lua'
    no file './llist.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/llist.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/llist.so'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/external/llist.so'
    no file '/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/llist.so'
: INFO (udf): (udf.c:954) lua error, ret:1
```

I could not find the relevant lua files or a lua installation in the container. I have my code working fine when I run it directly on the host. Is there some extra configuration that needs to be done to the container?

Comment: Which version of Aerospike are you using?

Answer (score 3):

LDTs were dropped in 3.15.

https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/ldt_guide.html

Excerpt:

> Aerospike has removed the Large Data Type feature as of server version 3.15 after deprecating this functionality 12 months earlier. Please see the removal notice and deprecation notice. The features listed below are no longer in Aerospike servers.